# Fluent UI, NormalPeoplePicker. How to pick suggested value with 'tab'?

Tags: reactjs, sharepoint, sharepoint-online, fluent-ui, fluentui-react

I have normal people picker dropdown with search. How can I pick first suggested value with 'tab' button?

[image]